# std::atomic_flag throws exception when I try to write to it with std::atomic_flag::test_and_set()

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm using the winapi to create a window. For ease of use, I want to wrap it in a C++ class.
When the destructor this class is called, I want to delete the window. However, if the window hasn't been loaded by the time the destructor is called, I.E the constructor of my wrapper class is called and immediately followed by the destructor, I have to need to wait for it to load.
To determine whether it's been loaded yet, I'm currently using an std::atomic_flag. I also tried using an atomic_bool but that had the same problem.
The exception is:
Exception thrown: write access violation.
**this** was nullptr.
It stems from test_and_set, as I said in the title, and happens somewhere in atomic_flag's exchange method.
The atomic_flag varirable is named "`windowLoadedYet`", and the offending piece of code is:

```
windowCreatedYet.test_and_set();
windowCreatedYet.notify_one();
```

Regrettably, This is my minimal producible result. I tried to make a smaller version, using atomic_bool in some test code, but unfortunately that code ran successfully.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
//#include "events.h"
#include <functional>
//#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <map>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
//int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {}
struct MirrageWindow {
    MirrageWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance) : hInstance(hInstance){
        activeInstancesLedger[hwnd] = this;
        //cout << "thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
        //std::jthread myThread(&MirrageWindow::maintainTheWindow, this);
        //maintainTheWindow();
        windowThread = std::jthread(&MirrageWindow::setup, this);
        
    }
    ~MirrageWindow() {
        if (!invalidated) {
            activeInstancesLedger.erase(hwnd);
            windowCreatedYet.wait(false);
            
            SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);
            cout << "posted message\n";
        }
    }
    MirrageWindow(const MirrageWindow& other) = delete;
private:
    bool invalidated = false;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    std::atomic_flag windowCreatedYet = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    std::jthread windowThread;
    LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcessMessage(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        //cout << "Message Recieved, loud and clear.\n";
        switch (uMsg)
        {
            case WM_CREATE:
                //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                //windowCreatedYet = false;
                windowCreatedYet.test_and_set();
                windowCreatedYet.notify_one();
                return 0;
            case WM_DESTROY:
                cout << "Quit message received\n";
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;

            case WM_PAINT:
            {

                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

                // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
                HBRUSH myCol = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(1, 255, 255));
                FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, myCol);
                RECT b{ 0,0,90,200 };
                //DrawText(hdc,L"It is disappointing when the toys you love don't love you back. This was Andy's struggle.",-1,&b, DT_BOTTOM | DT_WORDBREAK);
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                return 0;
            }
            case WM_NCHITTEST: {
                std::string a = "hi";
                time_t t = time(NULL);
                a += std::to_string(t);
                SetWindowTextA(hwnd, a.c_str());
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

                // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
                HBRUSH filler = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
                FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, filler);
                DeleteObject(filler);
                RECT b{ 0,0,90,200 };
                DrawText(hdc, L"You clicked. I knew you would.", -1, &b, DT_BOTTOM | DT_WORDBREAK);
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                return 0;

            }

        return 0;

        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    void registerWindowClassIfNotRegistered() {
        if (windowClasses.find(hInstance)==windowClasses.end()) {
            static uint_fast32_t id_counter = 0;
            id_counter++;
            std::wstring className = L"Class for Mirrage Windows in this hInstance";
            className+=L" id-num: "+(std::to_wstring(id_counter));
            windowClasses[hInstance] = className;
            WNDCLASS wc{};
            wc.hInstance = hInstance;
            wc.lpfnWndProc = &redirectorBecauseFuckC;
            wc.lpszClassName = className.c_str();
            RegisterClass(&wc);
        }
    }
    void createTheWindow() {
        cout << std::string(windowClasses[hInstance].begin(), windowClasses[hInstance].end());
        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,                               
            windowClasses[hInstance].c_str(),                     
            L"Learn to Program Windows, John.",
            WS_POPUP,            

            // Size and position
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

            NULL,       // Parent window    
            NULL,       // Menu
            hInstance,  // Instance handle
            NULL        // Additional application data
        );

        if (hwnd == NULL)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create window.");
        }
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(1, 2, 3), 100, LWA_ALPHA);
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
    void maintainTheWindow() {
        //cout << "running..\n";
        MSG msg = { };
        SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, -0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1), SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)

        {
            //cout << "transmitting message\n";
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    
    }
    void setup() {
        registerWindowClassIfNotRegistered();
        createTheWindow();
        maintainTheWindow();
    }
    
    static inline std::map<HINSTANCE, std::wstring> windowClasses;
    static inline std::map<HWND, MirrageWindow*> activeInstancesLedger;

    static LRESULT CALLBACK redirectorBecauseFuckC(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        MirrageWindow* redirect = activeInstancesLedger[hwnd];
        return redirect->windowProcessMessage(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};
int main() {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    
    MirrageWindow myWindow(hInstance);
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

Comment: Not an answer as I'm unsure but: Check that `this` is valid within windowProcessMessage -  I think it's possible that something is wrong with the way you use an `activeInstancesLedger` array to track HWNDs. (You would usually use [SetWindowLongPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra) to attach a pointer to your window object to the HWND.)

Comment: You are accessing `activeInstancesLedger` in the setup thread and at the same time erasing from it in the destructor. That's a data race.

Comment: You're right @user17732522. I can't believe I didn't effing see that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ethan McTagus, where were you last night to prevent me from committing this travesty. Thanks for the advice, I'll use it in the future.

Comment: Are you creating a new thread for every `MirrageWindow`? That looks wrong, and pretty much makes it impossible to have any sort of hierarchy of those windows, as explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683).